# Javascript selecting form elements using name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

Is it possible to select a form element using it's name attribute?

For example if I had something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="my_element" />
```

How would I go about setting a javascript variable to the value of this input?

```
var name_val = $(input[name='my_element']).val();
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your almost there

```
var name_val = $('input[name=my_element]').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var name_val = $('input[name="my_element"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
var name_val = $('input[name="my_element"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's even more simple: `$("#form_id").elements["my_element"]`