# javascript form selected name versus number

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ubercart

I read [Javascript selecting form elements using name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830833/javascript-selecting-form-elements-using-name-attribute) and from that have gotten the following form select working:

```
field_I_am_after: $(':input[name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_zone]"]').val(),
```

BUT it delivers the "selected" class NUMBER - in this case "12" from a group of State id's in an Ubercart form as follows:

```
<select id="edit-panes-delivery-address-delivery-zone" name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_zone]" class="form-select required">
 . . .  MORE . . . 
    <option value="11">Armed Forces Pacific</option>
    <option value="12" selected="selected">California</option>
    <option value="13">Colorado</option>
     . . .  MORE . . . 
</select>
```

I am trying to get the NAME for "selected" to go into / be the "field_I_am_after", that is i.e. => `$(' . . . option:selected').val()`,   or `.text()`,

I also reviewed [Get selected text from a drop-down list (select box) using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-drop-down-list-select-box-using-jquery) and tried most of what was suggested.  I am using JQuery 1.8 due to issues with ckeditor complaining about newer versions and not working with them

All the variants I tried to append this to my working statement have not worked

Can anyone see what have I done wrong - or incomplete ??

Comment: Try `$(':input[name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_zone]"] option:selected').text()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
field_i_am_after: $(':input[name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_zone]"] option:selected').text()
```

The first part of the selector finds the `<select>` element, then drills down to `option:selected` to find the option that the user has chosen, and then uses `.text()` to get its text content rather than the value.

```js
$(':input[name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_zone]"]').change(function() {
  $("#output").text(
    $(':input[name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_zone]"] option:selected ').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-panes-delivery-address-delivery-zone" name="panes[delivery][address][delivery_zone]" class="form-select required">
  <option value="11">Armed Forces Pacific</option>
  <option value="12" selected="selected">California</option>
  <option value="13">Colorado</option>
</select>
<br>Chosen: <span id="output"><span>
```

Comment: That did it.  I was putting the option:selected INSIDE the last "]" - and that is what I was doing wrong.